# Drawing polygon using event filter in Qt

Tags: qt, filter, polygon

I am working on a feature in my GUI that allow user to draw polygon by clicking the points.
First the user needs to enable this function by clicking a button. After that the user clicks any four points on the screen. When the fourth point is clicked, all the 4 points will be connected to form a polygon.

However the polygon is not appearing after the fourth is clicked. Instead there is a message of "QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1". What is the problem in my code?

```
bool QTGraphicsShape::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    double static x[4],y[4];
    int static i;
    if ((event->type() ==  QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseRelease) && (Draw3Points == true)) {
    QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast< QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* >( event );
    QPointF img_coord_pt = mouseEvent->scenePos();
    x[i] = img_coord_pt.x();
    y[i] = img_coord_pt.y();
    i++;
    if (i >= 4)
    {
        Draw3Points = false;
        i=0;
        static const QPointF points[4] = {
            QPointF(x[0], y[0]),
            QPointF(x[1], y[1]),
            QPointF(x[2], y[2]),
            QPointF(x[3], y[3])
        };
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.drawPolygon(points, 4);
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
  }
}

void QTGraphicsShape::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui.graphicsView->setMouseTracking(true);
    Draw3Points = true;
    m_pGraphicsScene->installEventFilter(this);
}
```

Comment: You can't draw on widgets outside of [paint event](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the eventFilter(..) to draw the polygon ?
As seen in your code that you are using QGraphicsScene/View
You can see the below implementation..
 **Note : Though the below implementation is for drawing a line on click points you can change it to draw a polygon ..**

You can derive the graphics view/scene and override the mousePressEvent

Below is example using derived QGraphicsScene and overridden mousePressEvent

Class Definition :

```
class MyScene : public QGraphicsScene
```

Data Members :

```
QList<QPointF> m_clickPositions;
int m_mode;
```

Code :

```
void MyScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(false == sceneRect().contains(event->scenePos()))
    {
        QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(event);
    }
    else if(Qt::LeftButton == event->button() && m_mode == ConstructMode)
    {
        m_clickPositions.append(event->scenePos());

        if(m_clickPositions.size() == 2)
        {
            QLineF lineF(m_clickPositions[0], m_clickPositions[1]);
            QGraphicsLineItem* item = this->addLine(lineF);
            m_clickPositions.clear();
            m_mode = ScrollMode;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Hope you find this useful.
Please comment if you have any problems

**EDIT ::** Added logic for activating construction mode in the above code.

ConstructMode and Scroll mode are used in the above program so that I can distinguish whether I want to Draw/Construct or just scroll the scene.

If you want to use the modes you can define some public constants and add a method setMode(). Please see the code below.

MyScene.h or some Constant file if you have one

```
#define ConstructMode 100
#define ScrollMode 101
```

And add the following function

```
void MyScene::setMode(int mode)
{
    m_mode = mode;
}
```

After this if you want to enter the construction mode you will need to call `myScene->setMode(ConstructMode)` every time, as after the item is constructed the mode is reset to ScrollMode or you can update the logic as per your need.

Hope you find it useful. Please comment if any problems.

Comment: Your advise is very useful. Thanks. The reason that I use event filter is that my drawing feature is only activated when I click certain button. Is my implementation correct in this case or actually is unnecessary? I am still new in Qt. Please advise.

Comment: @user3871571 : Please see the edits. I have updated the answer to have logic for entering construction mode.